# In JavaScript: Why doesn't setting a standard attribute's DOM property to an empty string remove the attribute like Element.removeAttribute() does?

Tags: javascript, dom

I've learned that it's generally best to use DOM properties to set, access, and modify attributes which has lead me to avoid using setAttribute() and getAttribute(). Is there a similar way to remove DOM attribute properties without using removeAttribute()?

Given this HTML code:

```
<div id=el></div>
```

And this JavaScript code:

```
let el = document.getElementById('el');
console.log(el.outerHTML); //<div id='el'></div>
console.log(el.align === ''); //true
el.align = 'center';
console.log(el.outerHTML); //<div id="el" align="center"></div>
el.align = '';
log(el.outerHTML); //<div id="el" align=""></div>
```

It appears that el.align is set to an empty string by default. Why does resetting el.align to an empty string after assigning a value to el.align not remove the align attribute from the el.outerHTML presentation? Is this method just as effective even so? Or will this cause issues that removeAttribute() won't?

Comment: Attributes and properties are different things, though some properties will result in an attribute change

Comment: better to use style/css for alignment also. A number of older attributes like `align` aren't used any more and are not suported in html5

Comment: It's worth noting that some attributes, such as [`align`](https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/present/graphics.html#h-15.1.2), have been deprecated and, as such, shouldn't be used at all (as @charlieftl already said, but it took me a while to find a W3 citation).

Comment: Not confident enough in this to answer officially, but my best guess is that it's because attributes can have empty values.

Answer (score 0):

You need to understand the difference between markup attributes and DOM properties. Attributes don't always directly align with with a property on the JavaScript object.

Comment: I think OP's confusion stems from the fact that setting the `align` property actually **does** create a DOM attribute

Answer (score 0):

The mapping between IDL attribute (properties) and the corresponding content attribute (markup) depends on the definition of this Interface Definition Language.

Setting some IDL attributes to `false` or `null` will remove them, for instance the ones mapping to [boolean attributes](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/common-microsyntaxes.html#boolean-attributes), whose simple presence signifies a truthy value:

```js
console.log(aud.loop);
console.log(aud.outerHTML);
aud.loop = false;
console.log(aud.outerHTML);
```

```html
<audio id='aud' loop></audio>
```

However, some others like [keywords attributes](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/common-microsyntaxes.html#keywords-and-enumerated-attributes) won't get removed, because the value you did set even if not part of the list of valid keywords will map to an *invalid default value*, for instance HTMLInputElement's `type` IDL will default to "text", if you set an invalid value, but the markup will still show this invalid value. (Your `align` attribute was part of this category, before it's been deprecated).

```js
console.log(inp.type); // "number"

inp.type = "foobar"; // invalid
console.log(inp.type); // => default to "text
console.log(inp.outerHTML); // markup: "foobar"

inp.type = null; // invalid
console.log(inp.type); // => default to "text
console.log(inp.outerHTML); // markup: "null"
```

```html
<input id="inp" type="number">
```

This makes sense since even though the browser doesn't recognize the set value as being one they support, it could very well be one that will be supported in the future.

The only way to remove such attributes is then to use `Element.removeAttribute()` method.

Same goes for other attributes which will accept any string as a valid value, for instance `class` (that is for HTML, CSS have stricter rules), here setting the IDL to any value will coerce it to a string, which will map to a valid in value in the IDL `className`.

```js
console.log(el.className); // ""

el.className = null; // coerced to string
console.log(el.className); // "null"
console.log(el.outerHTML); // markup: "null"

el.className = false; // coerced to string
console.log(el.className); // "false"
console.log(el.outerHTML); // markup: "false"

el.className = ""; // ""
console.log(el.className); // ""
console.log(el.outerHTML); // markup: ""
```

```html
<div id="el"></div>
```

And some will have different default values whether the attribute is *missing*, or in an *invalid* state, making their relation with the IDL even more obscure.

```js
// crossOrigin IDL when no set is `null`.
console.log(img.crossOrigin);// attribute unset => IDL `null`

img.crossOrigin = 'use-credentials' // only non default valid value.
console.log(img.crossOrigin);
console.log(img.outerHTML);

img.crossOrigin = false; // invalid 
console.log(img.crossOrigin); // IDL defaults to "anonymous"
console.log(img.outerHTML); // markup is `"false"`

img.crossOrigin = null; // remove
console.log(img.crossOrigin);
console.log(img.outerHTML);
```

```html
<img id="img">
```

Finally some won't get reflected at all in the content attribute, like the `HTMLInputElement.value`.

```js
inp.value = "new value";
console.log(inp.outerHTML);
```

```html
<input id="inp" value="initialValue">
```

So you'd need to search for the definition of any IDL attribute to be sure how it should behave.

Comment: Your example for keywords attributes is not good, since the class attribute does not take a set of keywords values. The align attribute on div elements is particularly odd in this respect, as it looks superficially as if it ought to take a one of a set of keywords ("left", "center", or "right") but in fact doesn't, any value is applicable, and other values just have no effect.

Comment: @Alohci You are right, class was not at the correct place. I fixed this example with a correct keyword attribute (input[type]) which does behave like `align` (the odd behavior your described is just the *invalid default value* behavior).